# c++ operator<< overloading not printing out vector

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, istream

I'm have trouble printing out a vector of my own class, `vector<Data> data;`.

Briefly, I'm working on a class `class Data_proc`, it has a constructor under public:

```
explicit Data_proc(const string& n, istream& is)
{
    Data temp;
    while(is >> temp)
        this->data.push_back(temp);
}
```

I have also overloaded `operator<<` for printing:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Data_proc& dp)
{
    os << "Person: " << dp.name
       << "\nnumber: " << dp.number;

    copy(dp.data.begin(), dp.data.end(), ostream_iterator<Data>(cout));

    return os;
}
```

The problem here is that code compiles with no problems, but nothing from the data vector is being printed out to the console. However, when I altered my constructor as following, it works, partially:

```
    Data temp;
    is >> temp;
    data.push_back(temp);
```

But as you might have suspected, this only prints out the first "pair", and the rest of data that were read from file are discard. What did I do wrong? Why didn't the `while`-loop keep reading from the file? Any help are appreciated! If you need details about the `class Data`, let me know!

Edit: `operator>>` for data, where I have `string staffName` and `vector<int> passCode`:

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Data& d)
{
    getline(is, d.staffName, '\n');

    int temp;
    while(is >> temp)
        d.passCode.push_back(temp);

    return is;
}
```

I can paste a snippet of how a input file's content looks like if it's also needed!

Edit 2: Added `operator<<` for `class Data`:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Data& d)
{
    os << d.staffName<< "\n";
    copy(d.passCode.begin(), d.passCode.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    return os;
}
```

Edit 3: Made a new `operator>>`:

```
    getline(is, d.staffName, '\n');

    string results;
    getline(is, results, '\n');
    istringstream iss(results);

    int val;
    while(iss >> val)
        d.passCode.push_back(val);

    return is;
```

Comment: Where is `operator >>` for `Data`?  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have added `operator>>`. Sorry for the long code.

Comment: @MikelF You mean how the `operator>>` was used in `main()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `operator>>`

```
while(is >> temp)
    d.passCode.push_back(temp);
```

This reads ints from the stream until failure. So whether it runs to the end of the stream, or until it tries to read something that cannot be interpreted as an int, the stream is guaranteed to be in a failure state when time the function ends. This means that in your constructor, the expression `is >> temp` will report as failed no matter the contents of the file, and no items will be put in the vector.

Comment: Umh, okay. My given input files contains first strings and then integers, and repeat. I made sure that the string is being read by `getline()`, so there is only integer left to be read until the next string appear, right?

Comment: What's a better approach if I'm to read a line of string and a line of integer repeated?

Comment: @user3941584: Use getline for the string, and then again for the integers (i.e. read all the integers on a line into a single string). Then use an `istringstream` to read from that string into a series of ints (in the same way you are doing now from the original stream).

Comment: Ok. I also read your answer in another post and you provided similar solution. I haven't made it to work yet, but I will give it another go.

Comment: I managed to print out the whole series by doing what you suggested. One thing that's strange is that every integer line print includes the previous values as well.

Comment: Might have been `copy(begin(), end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout));` that it's printing out the whole vector each time?

Comment: @user3941584: I can't see your code. I can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry I was trying out some codes, didn't work out so well. Anyways I added the new `operator>>`, and the `operator<<` is still the old one I was using. I'm thinking that I might need to use `map`?